# The ability-swap-circle chess

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

This question was inspired by this question: [A Battle of Dysfunctional Kings (Chess)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73620/a-battle-of-dysfunctional-kings-chess).

**What would be the shortest possible mate, if:**

- Every piece moves in the same way.
- The way the pieces move changes after each player ends their turn.
- All pieces start out moving like Pawns. On the next round, all pieces move like Queens; round after that: Knights, then Bishops, then Kings and finally Rooks. Then the cycle starts again (Pawn, Queen, ...).

That means:

- check is only when a figure moved and has changed movement

  - You can jump somewhere with the movement of the Knight and check as a Bishop
- White starts playing one of it's original Pawns, and then Black is attacked by 16 Queens, Black plays then a pawn and every piece of black changes the movement to a Queen

**Bonus:**
Would you like to play this in real? A whole Match?

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same movement"?

Comment: And yes, sure I would like to!

Comment: Do all pieces cycle at the same time, or does only the moved piece cycle?

Comment: @WaisKamal Every piece has the same movement, regardless if it was originally a rook or pawn. And the Movement changes for every piece

Comment: Again, what do you mean by movement? Do you mean all pieces move in the same way? If so, how do they move? Like a rook, queen, what? Please clarify.

Comment: @JoelRondeau as said before you have at the start 16 Pawns and when you end your turn (you moved a piece) you have 16 queens on the board

Comment: Does the king move as normal? Or the same as every piece?

Comment: The King doesn't move normal, it moves like the ability-swap-circle says. I should have called it the movement-swap-circle

Comment: I believe this is the intended interpretation: on White's first turn, **all** his pieces on the board move as if they were Pawns. Then on black's next turn, all his pieces move as if they were  Queens. On whites's next turn, all his pieces move as if they were Knights. On black's next turn, all his pieces move as if they were Bishops. On whites's next turn, all his pieces move as if they were Kings. On black's next turn, all his pieces move as if they were Rooks. This pattern continues, following the cycle as is written in the question: Pawn, Queen, Knight, Bishop, King and Rook

Comment: @Hugh I'm sry I should've specified more: white moves like a pawn, gets changed to queens. Black plays pawns and changes to queens. white plays queens and changes to knights and so on

Comment: Ah ok, I made some edits because so misunderstood it. Changing it might help.

Comment: @Hugh thank you very much :) That should clarify

Comment: When all pieces turn into Kings, does that mean check(mate) is possible on any piece, or only on the piece that looks like a King?

Comment: just the original king shall be in checkmate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: Using long notation for more simplicity)

I can do it on

> White's 3rd move

How:

> 1. h2-h4 f7-f6 2. Qg2-g4 Qe8-h5 3. Nh4-g6# (White's pieces are bishops, Black's knights.) 
>  Here's a link to it: https://lichess.org/study/6FOSi4Om

Update:

> I've been trying for hours now to get it down to Black's second move, and I don't think it can be done. Here's why: 
>  
>  First of all, Black's pieces are knights. It's very hard to checkmate a white king in the center of the board with knights only. I believe you need 5 with an optimal setup (Ke4, Nf6, Nd4, Nf4, Ng4, Ne2). This is... not going to be easy to get at all. And I'm pretty sure it's impossible. 
>  
>  Here's why. It's impossible to mate White on their first two ranks, because literally every possible checking square is guarded. However, if White moves beyond rank 2 on their first move, *they'll be in check by one of the black queens.* 
>  
>  So, there is literally only one possible square White can be checkmated on on move 3: **e3**. The only way for White to get to e3 is 1. e2-e4 2. Qe1-e3. However, there's one problem with being mated on e3. Remember the five knights earlier? Well, we've got the same problem. (Actually you need four, because d2 and f2 are occupied.) The problem still stands. You can only get two knights there in time. So, there is no way to checkmate White on move two.

Answer (score 1):

> On white's third move can be mate

How?

> 1.(Pawn) e2-e4, e7-e5
>  2.(Queen) e4xe5, e8xe5
>  3.(Knight) g1-e2#*
>  *you can do any move here, because after you set your pieces like a knight, they turn into a bishop and mate the King instantly